# How can you test if an object is another object

Tags: objective-c, pointers, swift

In objective c I could test if an object was the same as another by testing their pointers equivalence like this

```
- (BOOL) isSelected: (SomeObject *)object
{
    return object == theSelectedOne
}
```

Assuming theSelectedOne is a SomeObject *.  Is this possible in swift or should I make an identifying property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object identity in Swift is accomplished using `===`.

From **The Swift Programming Language > Classes and Structures**:

Note that “identical to” (represented by three equals signs, or ===) does not mean the same thing as “equal to” (represented by two equals signs, or ==):

- “Identical to” means that two constants or variables of class type refer to exactly the same class instance.
- “Equal to” means that two instances are considered “equal” or “equivalent” in value, for some appropriate meaning of “equal”, as defined by the type’s designer.